# how to set input field as readonly or entry field

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am having input item if data is available the field should be readonly else
required field.

```
  <input type="text" name="login_password" 
  id="login_password" 
 placeholder="Desgination" value="<?php echo 
   $row["designation"] ?>" Readonly required>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out, if there is some value in the field it will echo `readonly` else it will be blank field with `required`

```
<input type="text" name="login_password"   id="login_password"  placeholder="Desgination" value="<?php echo  $row["designation"]; ?>"  <?php if(trim($row["designation"]) !="") echo "Readonly"; else echo "required"; ?> >
```

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents! Without if inside the html code, a bad habit imho

```
$readonly = isset($row["designation"]) ? 'required' : '';

<input type="text" name="login_password" id="login_password" placeholder="Desgination" value="<?php echo $row["designation"] ?>" <?php echo $readonly; ?> required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php 
    if(!empty($row["designation"])){
       $condition = "readonly";
    else
      $condition = "required"; 
?>
<input type="text" name="login_password" id="login_password" placeholder="Desgination" value="<?php echo 
$row["designation"] ?>" <?php echo $condition; ?>>
```